# Google earth engine table export of multiple polygons

Tags: time-series, export-to-csv, polygon, google-earth-engine, timeserieschart

I have this script on GEE. I created a graph of time series of NDVI values with Sentinel 2 over multiple polygons (with removing of cloud pixels, overlapping tiles, etc). However, I wanted, instead of 3 graphs for each polygon, to export the values as a CSV file to run analysis in R. With on the first column the Date, then ID's polygons, and for each of them the NDVI value. But I don't know how to do it.
Here is the link to my script : https://code.earthengine.google.com/e4dfbdca171ef1bd6d92f62354880d0e